# jQuery fadeOut after scroll makes screen jump

Tags: jquery, html, css

On a site I'm building I have a fullscreen `.intro` DIV, when you click `.down` the page scrolls to the main content and the `.intro` div fades out.

All works as expected apart from after `.intro` fades out the page jumps down meaning the user has to scroll back up. Not ideal.

I can't figure out what the problem is. See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5nR2/1/) for a working example. I've used a gradient background so you can see the page jumping down after the (1500) it takes for `.intro` to `fadeOut`.

jQuery I am using:

```
(function($) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000); 
    });
});
})(jQuery);

$(".down").click(function() { 
$(".intro").fadeOut(1500);
});
```

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/B5nR2/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B5nR2/3/

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If you make it an actual answer I will mark it as right.

Comment: Sure, added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fadeOut()` fades out the element, and then sets the display property to `none`, taking the element out of the document flow, and that's why the page is jumping.

You can use either `fadeTo()` or animate the opacity to keep the element in place and avoid the jumping, but the element would still take up space even it's not visible.

```
$(".down").click(function() { 
    $(".intro").fadeTo(0);
});
```

or you can use the callback of the `fadeOut()` method to reset the scrollTop making it appear as the page didn't move, but this could cause some flashing in some browsers:

```
$(".intro").fadeOut(1500, function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0)
});
```