# Jquery Popup modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, popup

I'm creating a popup modal using Jquery and I have the code to work great. So when the user is scrolling to a certain px the popup menu will appear but now I want the popup to appear only on the landing page and not other pages.

Can I set the condition to window height and also the home page to equal to true before the popup appear? I appreciate any tips and help. Thank you, the script code is below.

```
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    var a = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (a > 800) {
        $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeIn();
    } else 

    $(".popup-close").click(function(e){
            closeSPopup();
        });
});

function closeSPopup(){
    $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: If you want this to be page specific, don't add this script to any shared script files, do it only on the home page.

Comment: @RyanWilson Hey Ryan, thank you for your feedback and you have a point but I am creating this code for a shopify store so for it to work, I think I have to include it in shopify theme.liquid. I gotta look into that.

Comment: You can use window.location.href to pull back the current url and then check if it is on the home page if you really need to include this script in some kind of shared file.

Comment: @RyanWilson You are right, I didn't even think about that so I place the code in a specific file page and it work great. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: @RyanWilson Hey Ryan, sorry to bother you again but I set up the close button to the popup and the button work but when the popup close it scroll the page back right up on top and I want the page to just stay. Is that something to do with the px I set in the condition?

Comment: I'd have to see your javascript code for the click event on your popup close button before I could analyze it.

Comment: @RyanWilson I will edit the question with the new code. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, just let me know when you have the question edited.

Comment: I just did it. thanks

Comment: I think this may have something to do with the .fadeout(), here is another post from SO that talks about the same issue you are facing: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023418/jquery-fadeout-after-scroll-makes-screen-jump)

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at that link.

Comment: no problem, I'm sorry but I have had no experience using jquery modals, I typically use Bootstrap modal windows in my web development.

Comment: Its alright. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. No need to apologize.